# Update Google Places API results using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API to get location details using javascript.

```
var request = {
            input: request.term,
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
            types: ['geocode']};

service.getPlacePredictions(request, function (predictions, status) {

    if (status != 'OK') {
        return;
    }
    response($.map(predictions, function (prediction, i) {
        var cty_st = '';

        var pred_terms_lnt = prediction.terms.length;

        if(pred_terms_lnt >= 3){
            cty_st = prediction.terms[pred_terms_lnt - 3].value+', '+prediction.terms[pred_terms_lnt - 2].value;
        }
        else if(pred_terms_lnt >= 2){
            cty_st = prediction.terms[pred_terms_lnt - 2].value;
        }
        else{
            cty_st = prediction.description.replace(", United States", "");
        }

        return {
            label: cty_st,
            value: cty_st,
            ref: prediction.reference,
            id: prediction.id
        }
  }));
 });
```

I want to show only city and state code from the results fetched and when I search for a location I'm getting duplicate city, state coder in the results. I want to remove these duplicates from the results. How to do that?

[image]

From the above results you can see last two results have same city and state code. I want to show only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `types: ['geocode']` use `types: ['(cities)']`